# Angular UI Grid - how to fetch sorted data from table

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

- I am using Angular UI Grid with Angular 1.x.
- Is there a way to fetch the sorted table data after the column is sorted.
- I understood that Angular UI Grid does sorting on a temp data (copy of original data), but is there a way to fetch this sorted data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows()
```

Or you can use more precisely:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
```

This will give array of rows in grid (with current sort condition)